# Folium draw and highlight polylines with distinct colours from unique GeoJSON

Tags: python, geojson, folium

### Main gist

I have a unique GeoJSON file (roads.geojson) that only contains multiple polylines.
Each polyline represent a road.

I want to display each entity (road/polyline) from that **same GeoJSON (layer)** with a unique color within the same layer (Road) and change the color/display on hover using the highlight function.

I want to use the highlight function specifically in order to display different info about each feature (polyline) like 'name', 'type' ... etc.

#### Visuals

| Wanted result | my actual results (problem) |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |
| all polylines from the same GeoJSON are displayed with their respective colors | all polylines from same GeoJSON are displayed with the same color according to `style_function` ignoring the GeoJSON properties. the `highlight_function` seems to apply to all features as well. |

### The problem

- I can't seem to be able to use the colors specified in the geojson for each polyline.
- All entities within the geojson take the same colors (`fillColor` for the stroke) specified in the `style_function` of the `folium.features.GeoJson` function
- There's no "`key_on`" parameter that I could use in my functions like it exists within the "`folium.choropleth`" function to specify properties (stroke color in this case) from the GeoJSON file.

#### My approach

Using `folium.features.GeoJson` with both style & highlight functions and displaying the rest of the info with `tooltip=folium.features.GeoJsonTooltip` as follows:

```
import folium
from folium import features
import geojson
import os
import webbrowser

# main map
m = folium.Map(location = [42.73894375124377, -75.21240234375], tiles='OpenStreetMap', zoom_start = 8, control_scale = True)

# linking to the geojson file
roads = os.path.join(r'roads.geojson')


# style function
roads_style_function = lambda x: {
  'color' :  'blue',
  'opacity' : 0.50,
  'weight' : 2,
}

# highlight function (change displayed on hover)
roads_highlight_function = lambda x: {
  'color': 'red', # stroke becomes red
  'opacity' : 0.9,
  'weight': 4,
  'dashArray' : '3, 6' # transforms the solid stroke to a dashed stroke
}

# main display function using the two previous functions
ROADS_INFO = folium.features.GeoJson(
  roads,
  name = 'roads',
  control = True,
  style_function = roads_style_function, 
  highlight_function = roads_highlight_function,
# the tooltip is where the info display happens
# using "folium.features.GeoJsonTooltip" function instead of basic text tooltip
  tooltip=folium.features.GeoJsonTooltip(
    # using fields from the geojson file
    fields=['Type', 'Name'],
    aliases=['Type: ', 'Name: '],
    style=("background-color: white; color: #333333; font-family: arial; font-size: 12px; padding: 10px;") # setting style for popup box
  )
)
m.add_child(ROADS_INFO)

# saving the map to html file and oppening it in default browser upon script execution
m.save('map.html')
webbrowser.open('map.html')
```

##### GeoJSON structure

You can copy/past it to [geojson.io](http://geojson.io) for quick vizualisation.
The geojson.io website recognizes the individual entity colors and displays them as such.

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "stroke": "#aa0000",
        "stroke-width": 4,
        "stroke-opacity": 1,
        "name": "Red road",
        "type": "main road"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            -75.41015624999999,
            44.715513732021336
          ],
          [
            -75.421142578125,
            41.376808565702355
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "stroke": "#33aa00",
        "stroke-width": 4,
        "stroke-opacity": 1,
        "name": "Green road",
        "type": "secondary road"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            -75.12451171875,
            44.70770622183535
          ],
          [
            -75.146484375,
            41.36031866306708
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "stroke": "#0011aa",
        "stroke-width": 4,
        "stroke-opacity": 1,
        "name": "Blue road",
        "type": "secondary road"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            -74.805908203125,
            44.72332018895825
          ],
          [
            -74.849853515625,
            41.335575973123916
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution (works perfectly)!

It appears it is possible to achieve what I set to (see main question) within the extent of the `style_function`.

- We can pass values to the style_function properties in a way that specifies any targeted properties within the geoJSON file as follows;

> solution inspired from [Thomas Gratier's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50302094/19362071)

### My approach

###### 1. Changing the values of the parameters withing both `style_function` and `highlight_function` (optional if highlight needed in `folium.features.GeoJson`)

| Before | After |
| --- | --- |
| `style_function = lambda x: {` `'color' : 'blue',` `'opacity' : 0.50,` `'weight' : '2',` `'dashArray' : '3, 6'` `}` | `style_function = lambda x: {` `'color' : x['properties']['stroke'],` `'opacity' : 0.50,` `'weight' : x['properties']['stroke-width'],` `'dashArray' : x['properties']['dashArray']` `}` |

###### 2. Changing the values of the parameters withing the GeoJSON file

| Before | After |
| --- | --- |
| `{` `"type": "FeatureCollection",` `"features": [` `{` `"type": "Feature",` `"properties": {` `"stroke": "#aa0000",` `"stroke-width": 4,` `"stroke-opacity": 1,` `"name": "Red road",` `"type": "main road"` `},` `"geometry": {` `"type": "LineString",` `"coordinates": [` `[` `-75.41015624999999,` `44.715513732021336` `],` `[` `-75.421142578125,` `41.376808565702355` `]` `]` `}` `},` `]` `}` | `{` `"type": "FeatureCollection",` `"features": [` `{` `"type": "Feature",` `"properties": {` `"stroke": "#aa0000",` `"stroke-width": 4,` `"stroke-opacity": 1,` `"dashArray-highlight": "1, 1",` `"dashArray": "1, 1",` `"name": "Red road",` `"type": "main road"` `},` `"geometry": {` `"type": "LineString",` `"coordinates": [` `[` `-75.41015624999999,` `44.715513732021336` `],` `[` `-75.421142578125,` `41.376808565702355` `]` `]` `}` `},` `]` `}` |

##### Full code

```
import folium
from folium import features
import geojson
import os
import webbrowser

# main map
m = folium.Map(
    location = [42.73894375124377, -75.21240234375],
    tiles='OpenStreetMap',
    zoom_start = 8, control_scale = True)

# linking to the geojson file
roads = os.path.join(r'roads.geojson')


# style function
roads_style_function = lambda x: {
  # specifying properties from GeoJSON
  'color' :   x['properties']['stroke'],
  'opacity' : 0.50,
  'weight' : x['properties']['stroke-width'],
  'dashArray' : x['properties']['dashArray']
}

# highlight function (change displayed on hover)
roads_highlight_function = lambda x: {
  'color' :   x['properties']['stroke'],
  'opacity' : 0.90,
  # specifying properties from GeoJSON
  'weight' : x['properties']['stroke-width'],
  'dashArray' : x['properties']['dashArray-highlight']
}

# main display function using the two previous functions
ROADS_INFO = folium.features.GeoJson(
  roads,
  name = 'roads',
  control = True,
  style_function = roads_style_function, 
  highlight_function = roads_highlight_function,
# the tooltip is where the info display happens
# using "folium.features.GeoJsonTooltip" function instead of basic text tooltip
  tooltip=folium.features.GeoJsonTooltip(
    # using fields from the geojson file
    fields=['Type', 'Name'],
    aliases=['Type: ', 'Name: '],
    style=("background-color: white; color: #333333; font-family: arial; font-size: 12px; padding: 10px;") # setting style for popup box
  )
)
m.add_child(ROADS_INFO)

# saving the map to html file and oppening it in default browser upon script execution
m.save('map.html')
webbrowser.open('map.html')
```

### Results

| Results - before hover | Results - on hover/highlight |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |